# CMake: how to use if condition in add_custom_command(...)

Tags: linux, bash, cmake, makefile, cmake-custom-command

I want to use Linux if condition in CMakeLists.txt by add_custom_command(...) for i need run these if condition and do some judgement in makefile. Like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_custom_target(temp_target ALL)
add_custom_command(TARGET temp_target
                   PRE_BUILD
                   COMMAND if ["a" != "b"]; then echo 1; fi;
                   VERBATIM )
```

What should i do if i want to use

```
if ["a" != "b"]; then echo 1; fi;
```

when make a makefile?
Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: if it doesnt work like that, why dont you try to add these in a function and then call the function in the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may specify one-line shell code with using `/bin/sh -c` as COMMAND argument:

```
COMMAND /bin/sh -c "if [ 'a' != 'b' ]; then echo 1; fi;"
```

Note, that `[` is an extension of the bash, it may be unknown for simple shells like "dash".

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but what you give seem does not work in my computer.

Comment: DONOT forget to add `VERBATIM` within `add_custom_command` !!

Comment: as @Master Yoda says, preceed semicolons with backslash

Comment: @jackytse: Inside a string, escaping of semicolons is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to preceed semicolons with backslash

```
COMMAND if [ 'a' != 'b' ] \; then echo 1\; fi\;
```